# How to redo this single Macro comand over every single row (e.g. from row 2 to row 500)

Tags: excel, vba, redo

I'm new programming over VBA; for the moment I have created a single macro for a single row-column; in this particular case for Row "2" and columns "M2:BF2" but I need this MACRO- command to run over the next 320 rows and I do not know how to do it. this is my command:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jageu.png)

I will appreciate any advice or guidance,

Best for everybody,

Jorge

Comment: Why not use a loop? A `for loop` is a natural choice. Also, please post your code rather than images of your code.

Answer (score 3):

Nested for loops are the way to go:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 2 To 320
        For j = 14 To 58 Step 2
            If Cells(i, j).Value = 0 Then Cells(i, j).Value = Cells(i, j - 1).Value
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

See [this](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html) for information about loops in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do this using Excel IF(condition, then, else) Formula.. Then once you complete one row, you can copy paste the same formula to all the rows and viola you have the answers.

Incase you insist on doing this using VBA, then you have to use a for loop.

```
  For i = 2 to 320
     If Range("N" & i).value = 0 then Range("N" & i).value = Range("M" & i).value
     '.... and so on...
  Next i
```

Comment: And there's a lot more simplification to do (look at the pattern of columns).